# Variables in wget post data

Tags: bash, variables, wget, postdata

I am working on a simple bash script to download images from the website Tumblr. The idea is to use `read` to get login info from the user, and `wget --post-data` to log in, and this is what I have:

```
read -p "Tumblr login email: " EMAIL
read -p "Tumblr login password: " PASSWRD
wget --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'email=$EMAIL&password=$PASSWRD' --no-check-certificate https://www.tumblr.com/login
```

However, it is sending `"$EMAIL"` and `"$PASSWRD"` instead of the strings for the variables, is there any way to get it to send values that have been inputted by the user?

Answer (score 63):

change:

```
--post-data 'email=$EMAIL&password=$PASSWRD'
```

to:

```
--post-data="email=$EMAIL&password=$PASSWRD"
```

bash manual about `Quoting`: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

Answer (score 4):

important:
Do not use :

```
--header="Content-Type: text/xml"
```

together with --post-data. It will override

```
--header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

issued by wget. Post-data will not be received by HttpServlet